# Powershell 365 - Remove email from distribution group

Tags: powershell

```
$Email = "@"
Get-DistributionGroup | where { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Name | foreach {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -contains "$Email"}
```

Results: Name, DisplayName, Group Type, PrimarySMTPAddress

I need to remove the user's email address from the distribution group. 
I know it will be a foreach command.

Does anyone know how to run that command?

Comment: Set-DistributionGroup “<Distribution Group name>” -EmailAddresses @{Remove='<Identity 1>', '<Identity 2>' }

Comment: But how do I send the `Get-DistributionGroup` into variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the If statement within a For loop that determines if the email address exists in the distribution group.

If this condition is satisfied, that's when you want to run the `Remove-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet:

```
$Email = "@"

Get-DistributionGroup | 
ForEach-Object { 
    If ((Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Name).PrimarySmtpAddress -contains $Email) { 
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Name -Member $Email -WhatIf}
    } 

}
```

Comment: I put in the email and got following warning back.

WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'DistributionGroup' have been modified.

Comment: Apologies, I specified the wrong cmdlet to remove the distribution group member. The ```Remove-DistributionGroup``` should work correctly. I updated my answer above. Make sure to remove the -WhatIf switch when you are satisfied with results.

Comment: I just ran your new command, then ran the check command again and still showing user is still apart of the distribution group

Comment: Figured it out, just had to remove `-WhatIf` then I added `-Confirm:$false`